# add a library object to stage with no linkage name

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, linkage

I'm trying to import an external SWF to my air app in iOS, and after many hours of troubleshooting have narrowed down the issue to the library objects' linkage names as being the last bit of "external code" that's preventing it from loading correctly.

So my question is, is there a way to add a library object to the stage without an "export for AS" linkage name?

Comment: the simple answer is no, in order for your code to have access to a library item it needs to be exported as a class. but that doesn't solve your problem, though you haven't really given enough information to know what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to load external SWF into a mobile app. You also can't load SWF even if it's packaged into an App.

Instead you can use SWC files that are packed into mobile app package and then added to the main movie using "Library path" option in the Publish settings.

You can produce SWC files (along with SWF) by selecting Publish format.

Comment: I already have it working in android and(to a lesser degree where I can add an swf with no "export for as" library objects) ios.  It downloads the swf file(that holds changing movieclips) to the application storage directory, then loads it from there.